# Java - create generic class type at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, runtime

I have below line of code

```
 public static String getVOFromJson (String jsonString, Sting className) throws IOException {
     // className value is "MatchDetailsVO"
    MatchDetailsVO obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MatchDetailsVO.class);
}
```

Don't want to hard code `MatchDetailsVO.class` but want to create the class type at runtime using the variable `className`

Comment: convert  to class  `Class.forName(className)`

Comment: getting error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? to MatchDetailsVO`

Comment: You are hardcoding `MatchDetailsVO` in `MatchDetailsVO obj`. Change it to `Object obj`.

Comment: @upog If you know that the class you pass is a subclass of `MatchDetailsVO`, you can use a cast. Otherwise, declare `obj` of type `Object`.

Comment: thanks you @Johannes Kuhn and @ Maurice Perry and @ Akash Shah

Comment: If you expect the class to be a subclass of `MatchDetailsVO`, use `Class.forName(className).asSubclass(MatchDetailsVO.class)`. This will throw an exception if the `className` passed is not a subclass of `MatchDetailsVO`.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your input

Comment: getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MatchDetailsVO`. i'm running this as spring boot app. i believe should update classppath of server to add this class

Comment: Pass the fully qualified name as String.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn  Thank you again. it's the missing package name caused the issue